# Ipod Nano 6th Generation Support

Tags: ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sync with iPod Nano 6G?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26353/how-to-sync-with-ipod-nano-6g)

Is it possible for ubuntu 10.10 (or any of its applications) to support ipod nano, 6th generation?