# How do I mount an iPod Touch with Banshee?

Tags: mount, banshee, ipod

I'm using the Banshee media player with my iPod Nano 5G and it works fine, but for some reason it won't recognise the Touch 2G at all this error message comes up:

> DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

How do I mount my iPod?

Thanks 
Robin

Comment: This is just a hunch but it might work to do what I did.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/27141/nothing-happens-when-i-connect-my-iphone-3g-to-my-laptop
Look at my accepted answer, on edit2!

Comment: did you do an initial sync in itunes?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, Banshee, and iPod firmware?

Answer (score 4):

Just follow this instructions:

1. Execute this:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa`
   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

   Just in case, execute this (unless you know you have both installed):

   `sudo apt-get install ifuse gvfs libimobiledevice1`
2. Connect your iDevice and execute:

   `idevicepair unpair`
3. With the iDevice plugged, unlock the screen and execute:

   `idevicepair pair`
   `idevicepair validate`
4. Unplug the device and plug it in again, it should now mount as it did before

---

This problem is caused by a bug in the 4.2.1 update.

Comment: Sorry that was my "hunch"

Comment: Followed those instructions, but was given the error that libimobiledevice1 no longer existed, and to try libimobiledevice2, (which I did) and then the error idevicepair: command not found.

Comment: You may also need to install libimobiledevice-utils (to get idevicepair).