# iPhone mounting problem: idevicepair command not found

Tags: 11.04, iphone

I've been following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27141/nothing-happens-when-i-connect-my-iphone-3g-to-my-laptop/27163#27163) for trying to read my iPhone from Ubuntu. I'm still getting the error in the question. Under Edit 2 of the answer it says to run

```
idevicepair unpair
```

But I tried that and just get

```
idevicepair: command not found
```

Tried installing idevicepair but no package can be located. What do I need to do to get my iPhone (3GS) working under Ubuntu (11.04)?

Comment: Please can you add the link to "this answer" into your question.  Thanks.

Comment: @foss, d'oh! I copied the URL and everything and forgot to link it /facepalm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the package `libimobiledevice-utils` available in the software center

i.e.

in a terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
```